# Matrices satisfying the following relation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find complex matrices $M_1, M_2, M_3$ such that
$$M_i M_j + M_j M_i = 0$$
for $i \neq j$, and $M_i^2 = I$.

I am stuck. Is the expression $AB + BA$ called something? It's sort of like a commutator.

Comment: $AB=-BA$ would be called "anti-commutative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pauli matrices should do the job,

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PauliMatrices.html

The matrices are,

$$ \sigma_1 = \left(\begin{array} &0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right) $$

$$ \sigma_2 = \left(\begin{array} &0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array}\right) $$

$$ \sigma_1 = \left(\begin{array} &1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right) $$

Some algebra should convince you they satisfy your equalities.

Comment: Great, exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Having a physics background I just had to answer this one :).

Answer (score 1):

From $M_i^2 = I$, we have that $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ serves as an appropriate basis element.

Since $M$ are taken over the complex numbers, it should be simple enough to derive similar matrices using $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Finally, test all combinations of these basis matrices in the desired identity. You should get what you're looking for rather easily.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail. How are we sure the nonzero entries of the matrix must all be $\pm 1, \pm i$? Why not magnitude 1, or other values?

Comment: *A priori*, we're not... at least not necessarily. However, the condition $M_i^2 = I$ suggests that if you have a diagonal or anti-diagonal matrix, you will want the non-zero elements to have modulus 1. And the simplest matrices that satisfy commutativity-like properties are diagonal matrices. So it's a good place to start. Actually, you can probably make this much more rigorous using some basic group-theory arguments, but a constructive approach sometimes is more illuminating